# GeoDjango and postgis setup in docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, postgis, geodjango

I'm trying to create a docker setup such that I can easily build and deploy a geodjango app (with postgis backend). I have the following folder structure:

```
|-- Dockerfile
|-- Pipfile
|-- Pipfile.lock
|-- README.md
|-- app
|   |-- manage.py
|   |-- app
|   `-- app_web
```

In my Dockerfile to setup Django I have the following:

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.7

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN pip install pipenv
COPY . /code
WORKDIR /code/
RUN pipenv install --system

# Setup GDAL
RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin python-gdal python3-gdal

# set work directory
WORKDIR /code/app
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "migrate", "--no-input"]
```

In my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    postgis:
        image: kartoza/postgis:12.1
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    web:
        build: .
        command: python /code/app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        volumes:
            - .:/code
        depends_on:
            - postgis
volumes:
    postgres_data:
```

And finally in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
         'NAME': 'postgres',
         'USER': 'postgres',
         'HOST': 'postgis',
    },
}
```

Now when I: run docker-compose up --build
It all seems to work (both the database as well as the django app spin up their containers). But whenever I try to actually work with the database (the app is blank rightnow, so I still need to migrate) django doesn't seem to recognize the database.

Can anybody tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: Did you find out what the problem was?

Answer (score 1):

> run docker-compose up --build It all seems to work (both the database as well as the django app spin up their containers)

Make sure to **check the logs** because containers not necessarily stop after finding an error.

```sh
docker-compose logs
```

Also you're already setting your working dir in **Dockerfile**

```
WORKDIR /code/app
```

so take a look at the command you execute in **docker-compose.yml**:

```
command: python /code/app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Answer (score 1):

In settings.py, `PASSWORD` needs to be specified:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
         'NAME': 'postgres',
         'USER': 'postgres',
         'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
         'HOST': 'postgis',
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the app?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # [...]
    'django.contrib.gis'
]
```